anova.mitml.results giving high df2 when comparing nested models
I'm comparing nested models using anova.mitml.results to test my fixed effects.
I have 25 imputed datasets, 231 participants per time measure x 3 time measures. I'm not familiar with the D3 method of combination. I have high df2 values, varying despite equal df1 and I'm not sure if this is normal. I tried to cross-checked my reprex with SPSS unpooled results of type III fixed test and my df2 are around 47 and the same given the same df1.
Because I'm new to R, I cross-check with SPSS the type III fixed effect test, and because of the discrepancies below in my df2, I'm not sure if I can trust my R results.
MY QUESTION:

Is there anything in my code or model comparison that could lead to wrong results?
1.1 Is is normal when using the D3 method (Meng and Rubin,1992) to have higher DF2 then with type III ANOVA on a single dataset.
1.2. Compared to a type III ANOVA on a single dataset set, is it normal for df2 to vary for a model using the same DV, but a different variable with the same number of levels as below.

Some of my df1 data (dput) for reprex. 5 imputed data sets for 20 individuals x 3 time measures:
structure(list(imp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
     2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
     2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
     2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
     3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
     3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
     3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
     4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
     4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,
     5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
     5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
     5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
 Subj = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7,
    7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
    13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 
    19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
    5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12,
    12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 
    17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
    11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 
    16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9,
    9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 
    15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 
    20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 
    13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 
    18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,
    5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 
    12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 
    17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20 ), 
 X1 = c(0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3,
    0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 
    1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
    3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 
    0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 
    1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1,
    3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3,
    0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 
    1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
    3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 
    0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0,
    1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
    3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 
    0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 
    1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
    3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 
    0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3), 
 X2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
 X3 = c(28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 
    53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 
    52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 
    30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 
    37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42,
    42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 
    23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 
    35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 
    36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 
    25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 
    49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 
    34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 
    57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 
    21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 
    39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 
    42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 
    53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 
    52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 
    30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 
    37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 
    42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 
    23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 
    35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42), 
 X4 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2,
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1,
    1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), 
 X5 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
     2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
     2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
     2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
 Dependant = c(32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, NA, NA, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 
   14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, NA, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3,
   7, 0, NA, 17, 3, NA, 40, 25, 21, 35, NA, NA, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 
   22, 20, NA, 18, 23, 10, 13, 14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 
   8, 34, 22.74679565, 9.078754233, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
   12, 21, 23.89331785, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 
   9.563034676, 17, 3, 8.171110057, 40, 25, 21, 35, 13.53468633, 
   21.4990267, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 10.75448127, 18, 23, 10, 
   13, 14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 23.678318, 
   6.38024107, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 15.33803817, 
   20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 26.37095017, 17, 3, 
   5.8830194, 40, 25, 21, 35, 17.5314952, 13.24750912, 17, 5, 4, 27, 
   8, 4, 22, 20, 16.64639694, 18, 23, 10, 13, 14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 
   11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 24.23722065, 14.13450552, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 
   14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 21.8956743, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16,
   6, 3, 7, 0, 13.31806771, 17, 3, 12.46910086, 40, 25, 21, 35, 
   5.346067919, 14.71408964, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 9.644988209,
   18, 23, 10, 13, 14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 
   16.25464311, 14.55203722, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21,
   20.15197466, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 
   7.169741223, 17, 3, 15.89606111, 40, 25, 21, 35, 8.178602917, 
   -2.653330003, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 17.11276677, 18, 23, 10,
   13, 14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 28.30217443, 
   7.983293096, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 
   -2.445506679, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 
   0.897162825, 17, 3, 12.38497675, 40, 25, 21, 35, 13.76105932, 
   23.24251938, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 9.744084982, 18, 23, 10, 
   13, 14, 4, 15, 12, 14)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -360L), 
  variable.labels = c(imp = "", Subj = "", X1 = "Temps", 
                      X2 = "PsychoT1", X3 = "T0_age", X4 = "Group", 
                      X5 = "Sexe", Dependant = "Dependant" ), 
 codepage = 65001L)

The full model is
Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X2*X4*X1 + (1| Subj)))

Using my first dichotomic variable compared to the null model to test the effect of X2, df1=1
library(mice)
library(lme4)
library(datawizard)
library(mitml)

df1 <- datawizard::to_factor(df1, c("X1","X2", "X4", "X6"))
df.mids1 <- as.mids(long=df1, .imp="imp")
implist1 <- mids2mitml.list(df.mids1)

Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X2 +
                                   (1| Subj)))

Lmer.X21 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~
                                    (1| Subj)))

anova.mitml.result(Lmer.X2, Lmer.X21)
#> 
#> Call:
#> 
#> anova.mitml.result(object = Lmer.X2, Lmer.X21)
#> 
#> Model comparison calculated from 5 imputed data sets.
#> Combination method: D3
#> 
#> Model 1: Dependant ~ X2 + (1 | Subj)
#> Model 2: Dependant ~ (1 | Subj)
#> 
#>            F.value     df1     df2   P(>F)     RIV 
#>    1 vs 2    3.381       1 342.175   0.067   0.121 
#> 
#> Models were automatically ordered via 'logLik' (by decreasing complexity).
#> Models originally fit with REML were automatically refit using ML.


Using my second dichotomic variable compared to the null model to test the effect of X4, df1=1 also
Lmer.X3 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X4 +
                                   (1| Subj)))

Lmer.X31 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~
                                    (1| Subj)))

anova.mitml.result(Lmer.X3, Lmer.X31)
#> 
#> Call:
#> 
#> anova.mitml.result(object = Lmer.X2, Lmer.X21)
#> 
#> Model comparison calculated from 5 imputed data sets.
#> Combination method: D3
#> 
#> Model 1: Dependant ~ X4 + (1 | Subj)
#> Model 2: Dependant ~ (1 | Subj)
#> 
#>            F.value     df1     df2   P(>F)     RIV 
#>    1 vs 2    0.929       1 444.087   0.336   0.105 
#> 
#> Models were automatically ordered via 'logLik' (by decreasing complexity).
#> Models originally fit with REML were automatically refit using ML.

Screenshot of SPSS output for Type III fixed effect test for the same variable for 1 multiply imputed datasets:(https://i.sstatic.net/8oyEeNTK.png)
Another example, using the baseline variable (did not have missing data to impute) of X2 (X6), to test the effect of X6:
Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X6 +
                                   (1| Subj)))

Lmer.X21 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~
                                    (1| Subj)))


anova.mitml.result(Lmer.X2,Lmer.X21)
#> 
#> Call:
#> 
#> anova.mitml.result(object = Lmer.X2, Lmer.X21)
#> 
#> Model comparison calculated from 5 imputed data sets.
#> Combination method: D3
#> 
#> Model 1: Dependant ~ X6 + (1 | Subj)
#> Model 2: Dependant ~ (1 | Subj)
#> 
#>            F.value     df1     df2   P(>F)     RIV 
#>    1 vs 2    1.626       1 269.046   0.203   0.139 
#> 
#> Models were automatically ordered via 'logLik' (by decreasing complexity).
#> Models originally fit with REML were automatically refit using ML.

SPSS output from a multiply imputed dataset (df1|df2|F|p-value):(https://i.sstatic.net/lv5Mgr9F.png)
I also have the same preoccupation when I test my interactions, example :
To test the effect of my three-way interaction (X1 has 3 levels)
 Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X2 + X4 + X1:X4 + 
                  X2:X4 + X1:X2 + X1:X2:X4 +(1| Subj)))
 Lmer.X21 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X2 + X4 + X1:X4 + 
                   X2:X4 + X1:X2 + (1| Subj)))


To test the effect of my two-way interactions
 Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X2 + X4 + X2:X4 + 
                                            (1| Subj)))
 Lmer.X21 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X2 + X4 + (1| Subj)))

 Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X2 + X1:X2 + 
                                            (1| Subj)))
 Lmer.X21 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X2 + 
                                             (1| Subj)))

 Lmer.X2 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X4 + X1:X4 + 
                                            (1| Subj)))
 Lmer.X21 <- with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1 + X4 + (1| Subj)))

